# Is this way to multiply matrices valid?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is an upper triangular matrix and nonsingular. Say it is 3 by 3. We know there is some $A$ such that $AU = I_3$. Let $A = [a_1,a_2,a_3]$ where $a_i$ are column vectors. Let $u_1 = (u_{11},0,0)^T$, $u_2 = (u_{12},u_{22}, 0)^T$, $u_3 = (u_{13}, u_{23}, u_{33})^T$ be column vectors of $U$. Then,

$$ AU = I_3 \implies a_iu_i = e_i $$

where $(e_i)$ are standard basis. and so we have the following system of equations:

$$ a_1u_{11} = e_1, a_1 u_{12} + a_2 u_{22} = e_2, a_1 u_{13} + a_2 u_{23} + a_3 u_{33} = e_3  $$

I dont understand how this system of equations follows from $AU = I_3$. Can someone explain this procedure to me? thanks

Comment: $a_iu_i = e_i$ doesn't make sense.  I think perhaps you mean $a_iu_{ij} = e_j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$AU = I_3 \iff \begin{bmatrix} Au_1 & Au_2 & Au_3\end{bmatrix} = I_3 \\ \iff \begin{cases}Au_1 = e_1 \\ Au_2 = e_2 \\ Au_3 = e_3\end{cases} \\ \iff \begin{cases} A(u_{11}e_1) = e_1 \\ A(u_{12}e_1 + u_{22}e_2) = e_2 \\ A(u_{13}e_1 + u_{23}e_2 + u_{33}e_3) = e_3\end{cases} \\ \iff \begin{cases} u_{11}(Ae_1) = e_1 \\ u_{12}(Ae_1) + u_{22}(Ae_2) = e_2 \\ u_{13}(Ae_1) + u_{23}(Ae_2) + u_{33}(Ae_3) = e_3\end{cases} \\ \iff \begin{cases} u_{11}a_1=e_1 \\ u_{12}a_1+u_{22}a_2 = e_2 \\ u_{13}a_1 + u_{23}a_2 + u_{33}a_3=e_3\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the definition of $U$:
\begin{align}
AU &= A [u_1, u_2, u_3]
= [A u_1, A u_2, A u_3]
= [a_1 u_{11}, a_1 u_{12}+a_2 u_{22},a_1 u_{13}+a_2 u_{23}+a_3 u_{33}] \\
&= I = [e_1,e_2,e_3]
\end{align}
and the equate the column vectors.